# How to find the min positive number within a list

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
lst = [0, 500.0, 500.0, 240.0]
```

and I want to find the index of the smallest number that is positive and above 0.

```
index_of_small = lst.index(min(lst))
```

I expect `index_of_small` to be index of `3` instead of index of `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `index_of_small = lst.index(min(filter(lambda x : x > 0, lst)))`. Filter before finding min.

Answer (score 3):

Using [min() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)

```
lst = [0, 500.0, 500.0, 240.0,1.0,-1.0]

print(min(n for n in lst  if n>0))
```

O/P:

```
1.0
```

Comment: I'd remove `[]`-brackets to make sure it takes only one pass. Also, the OP wants the _index_ of the min elem.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to find the min element and then find its index, like in another answer. That however makes two passes over the list. It one pass that will be:

```
min((a,i) for i, a in enumerate(lst) if a>0)[1]
```

This uses the fact that tuples are compared element by element, left to right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the 0 and find the min, then get the index of this min

```
lst.index(min(i for i in lst if i > 0))
```